# Redirect non HTTPS to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to force non HTTPS visitors to HTTPS, see my code below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%$1 [R,L]
```

It redirects **example.com** to **https://example.com/index.php**
I just want **example.com** to redirect to **https://example.com**

Please help.

Comment: You can try this: `RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%$1 [R,L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the order:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```